# Formatting Pandas Dataframe for Plotting a Graph

Tags: python, pandas

I have loaded my data into pandas dataframe and one of the columns in my dataframe has values like the following. I need to count each fruits count and pass on its value to a dataprovider for plotting a graph.

```
************************
Data in the Dataframe
************************
orange
apple
grapes
mango
orange
orange
orange
mango
apple
```

For example, I wanted to pass the values into the dataProvider in the below format.

```
"dataProvider": [{
    "flavor": "orange",
    "count": 4
  }, {
    "flavor": "apple",
    "count": 2
  }, {
    "flavor": "grapes",
    "count": 1
  }, {
    "flavor": "mango",
    "count": 2
  }],
```

Basically what I wanted to get is the following format from the above data.

```
[{
    "flavor": "orange",
    "count": 4
  }, {
    "flavor": "apple",
    "count": 2
  }, {
    "flavor": "grapes",
    "count": 1
  }, {
    "flavor": "mango",
    "count": 2
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for count, then convert index to column by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and last convert to `list of dict`s by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print (df)
   flavor
0  orange
1   apple
2  grapes
3   mango
4  orange
5  orange
6  orange
7   mango
8   apple

d = df.groupby('flavor', sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count').to_dict('r')
print (d)
[{'count': 4, 'flavor': 'orange'}, 
 {'count': 2, 'flavor': 'apple'}, 
 {'count': 1, 'flavor': 'grapes'}, 
 {'count': 2, 'flavor': 'mango'}]
```

---

```
d = (df['flavor'].value_counts(sort=False)
                 .rename_axis('flavor')
                 .reset_index(name='count')
                 .to_dict('r'))
print (d)
[{'count': 1, 'flavor': 'grapes'}, 
 {'count': 2, 'flavor': 'apple'}, 
 {'count': 2, 'flavor': 'mango'},
 {'count': 4, 'flavor': 'orange'}]
```

Comment: I am getting a keyerror while executing the above code. Can you please help me out to point out, what I am missing? Here is how it looks like https://dpaste.de/Cazp

Comment: Use `df_data.groupby('flavor', sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count').to_dict('r')`

Comment: @GokulnathKumar - there is problem `df1` is `Series`, not `DataFrame`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data frame, `df`, looks like:

```
   flavor
0  orange
1   apple
2  grapes
3   mango
4  orange
5  orange
6  orange
7   mango
8   apple
```

You could use `pd.factorize` in a comprehension:

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.flavor)
[dict(count=c, flavor=f) for c, f in zip(np.bincount(f), u)]

[{'count': 4, 'flavor': 'orange'},
 {'count': 2, 'flavor': 'apple'},
 {'count': 1, 'flavor': 'grapes'},
 {'count': 2, 'flavor': 'mango'}]
```

---

Alternatively, you could have used `pd.Series.value_counts` to perform a similar task as `factorize` and `bincount`

```
s = df.flavor.value_counts()
[dict(count=c, flavor=f) for c, f in zip(s.values, s.index)]

[{'count': 4, 'flavor': 'orange'},
 {'count': 2, 'flavor': 'apple'},
 {'count': 1, 'flavor': 'grapes'},
 {'count': 2, 'flavor': 'mango'}]
```